# Correct way to determine if javascript is enabled

Tags: javascript, html

I've been checking questions and answers here (and elsewhere) without getting a clear answer:
Are there any drawbacks with the following html to display an alternate image if javascript is disabled?

```
<html>  
<head>  
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>  
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js">  </script>  
    <script src="path to local js script here"></script>  
    <noscript><a href="URL here" target="_blank"><img src="path to alt image here" />  </a></noscript>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path to css here">  
</head>  
<body>  
...
</body>  
</html>
```

This appears to be working for me, but I've seen more complicated solutions suggested; Is there anything 'wrong' with making an alt image this way?

Comment: Putting an `<a>` in the `<head>` is a little weird.

Comment: What is the original problem that this is supposed to solve? How would the image be “alternative”?

Comment: If the user has javascript enabled the page will be populated with content via jQuery. If javascript is disabled I'd like to display an alternate image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is invalid HTML; you cannot put content in the `<head>`.

Move it to the `<body>` and it'll be fine.

Note that if the user has Javascript enabled, but a proxy is removing your scripts, that won't be displayed.
Instead, you can put a `no-js` class in your `<html>`, then add a bit of Javascript to the `<head>` that replaces it with a `js` class.
You can then write CSS rules that apply only if Javascript is actually working.

Comment: OK, thanks for the answer. WHAT won't be displayed if a proxy is removing my scripts? If you mean that the <noscript> section won't be displayed, that's fine because the user has js enabled, right?

Comment: @moosefetcher: The `<noscript>` section won't be displayed, but if a proxy strips out the script tags, then the scripts won't run either.  So you end up with no message *and* no scripts.  You should consider the `no-js` class or something similar, that only hides when scripts are actually there and running (as opposed to when the browser *can* run scripts, for those weird cases where it never sees them).

Comment: OK, so the page didn't display your reply until I'd added this comment! (which I'm now editting, somewhat pointlessly). Thanks for the reply.